# Is it safe to store my database backup in version control?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do `pg_dump mydb > backup.sql` to backup my postgres database. It dumps my database onto a file called `backup.sql`. Should I add `.sql` to `.gitignore` or is the database not sensitive data?

PS: I'm using Django/Ubuntu backend.

Comment: That would highly depend on whether its your production database or local one. If its the production database and you store sensitive information in it, again it will highly depend on what kind of version control service you use and how secure is the transfer/their service and whole lot of other factors. **If your database is huge then you should just get a proper backup service, and only dump your structures and no data for the version control and leave the full backup for your backup service.**

Comment: I see no advantage to storing the database file in version control.  I would recommend ignoring it and using some other archiving solution.

Comment: Can you give a suggestion? @GordonLinoff

Comment: If you have enough access to run `pg_dump` you should also know whether the database has too sensitive data for "version control". If not, your boss shouldn't have given you that access. It also depends on the VC system. If it's the same group of people that has access there as to the database, the risk is the same (withholding the increased risk of more security holes or slip ups that comes from including more software to the loop) If you are serious about backup in PostgreSQL, read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html

Comment: But if git is unconventional - where else do I store the `backup.sql` file? That's the reason I want to use git - to protect the file incase something happens to my server and I lose it. @KjetilS.

Comment: How important, in your database, is it to be able to recover all commit-ed changes up until the disk on the main database server crashed? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/warm-standby.html#SYNCHRONOUS-REPLICATION has info on this. Storing all changes to a standby/second server (preferably not in the same room or building or not even in the same town in case of flooding or war) and not permitting new changes before the last `commit` is confirmed stored on the standby server, is called synchronous replication. `pg_dump` is not the right tool if you want this level of backup.